# Label Ruby One letter

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure this out. I am working on a ruby code where in I want to label each array item where in users can just type 1 letter such as l for lego and so on and it will accept that and validates/check that on the code inside the array.

```
MY_CHOICES = %w(lego violin xray)

l = "lego"
v = "violin"
x = "xray"

print "Choose one: #{MY_CHOICES.join(', ')} "
choice = gets.chomp

if MY_CHOICES.include?(choice)
  break
else
  puts "That is not included there."
end
```

Any idea how to do it? Sorry newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MY_CHOICES = {
  'l' => 'lego',
  'v' => 'violin',
  'x' => 'xray'
}

print "Choose one: #{MY_CHOICES.values.join(', ')} "
choice = gets.chomp

if MY_CHOICES[choice]
  puts "#{MY_CHOICES[choice]} chosen"
else
  puts "That is not included there."
end
```

Comment: Can  you explain further?

Comment: How does that .zip works? and how does it works on the puts.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-zip or use the simplified version by @spickermann